# Postfix, TLS and StartSSL certificates

Tags: ssl, postfix, smtp, tls, certificate-authority

I recently changed my postfix installation to use TLS with a certificate issued by StartSSL. I then ran [SMTP](http://www.checktls.com) and [TLS](http://mxtoolbox.com) checks with no errors or warnings. Everything seemed to work fine.

My problem now is, that receiving mails doesn't seem to work in every case. There seem to be mail servers I cannot receive mails from. These are for example Amazon or Blizzard.
In Amazon's case my postfix log has this to say:

```
Jan 16 13:57:51 myhost postfix/smtpd[31551]: connect from mm-notify-out-127-214.amazon.com[176.32.127.214]
Jan 16 13:57:51 myhost postfix/smtpd[31551]: lost connection after EHLO from mm-notify-out-127-214.amazon.com[176.32.127.214]
Jan 16 13:57:51 myhost postfix/smtpd[31551]: disconnect from mm-notify-out-127-214.amazon.com[176.32.127.214]
```

When receiving mails from Blizzard the log looks the same, except that the "lost connection" line is missing.

I suspect that the StartSSL certificate may not be trusted by these two (and possibly more) companies and that I have to buy a certificate from a large, "trustworthy" CA.

Can anyone tell if my suspicion is correct or if there are any mistakes I could've made in my postfix configuration?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

**Edit:**
This is my output from a telnet session:

```
telnet host 587
Trying ip...
Connected to host.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 host ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
ehlo host
250-host
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 134217728
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

**Edit:**
Postfix log with debug_peer_list enabled:

```
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/tlsmgr[5714]: open smtpd TLS cache btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/tlsmgr[5714]: tlsmgr_cache_run_event: start TLS smtpd session cache cleanup
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: connect from smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostname: smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostaddr: 176.32.127.108 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostname: smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostaddr: 176.32.127.108 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostname: smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com ~? [::1]/128
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostaddr: 176.32.127.108 ~? [::1]/128
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_list_match: smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com: no match
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_list_match: 176.32.127.108: no match
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: auto_clnt_open: connected to private/anvil
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: send attr request = connect
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: send attr ident = smtp:176.32.127.108
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute name: status
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute value: 0
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: count
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute name: count
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute value: 1
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute name: rate
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute value: 1
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute name: (end)
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 220 mail.myhost ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: watchdog_pat: 0x7fa2f92c07b0
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: < smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: EHLO smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 250-mail.myhost
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 250-PIPELINING
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 250-SIZE 134217728
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 250-VRFY
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 250-ETRN
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_list_match: smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com: no match
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_list_match: 176.32.127.108: no match
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 250-STARTTLS
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 250-8BITMIME
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 250 DSN
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: watchdog_pat: 0x7fa2f92c07b0
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: < smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: MAIL FROM:<20140116155221ae18abe030864bbfaaa9b8af73986be6@bounces.amazon.de> SIZE=27930
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: watchdog_pat: 0x7fa2f92c07b0
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: < smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: RSET
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: > smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: watchdog_pat: 0x7fa2f92c07b0
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: smtp_get: EOF
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostname: smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostaddr: 176.32.127.108 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostname: smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostaddr: 176.32.127.108 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostname: smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com ~? [::1]/128
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_hostaddr: 176.32.127.108 ~? [::1]/128
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_list_match: smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com: no match
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: match_list_match: 176.32.127.108: no match
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: send attr request = disconnect
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: send attr ident = smtp:176.32.127.108
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute name: status
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute value: 0
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: input attribute name: (end)
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: lost connection after EHLO from smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]
Jan 16 16:52:21 myhost postfix/smtpd[5712]: disconnect from smtp-out-127-108.amazon.com[176.32.127.108]
```

Comment: Are you doing TLS on port 25? you might just want to do it on the submission ports, and leave port 25 not offering SSL..

Comment: @NickW thank you for the hint. TLS was indeed only running on port 25. I changed it to solely use the submission port. Unfortunately that did not solve my problem

Comment: That is odd, so things were working before, correct? What else did you change besides adding TLS?

Comment: Telnet into port 25 and run "EHLO hostname" to see what services are offered and post the results here.

Comment: Also, did you get the chained certs installed as well? Those usually go into the pem file along with your actual cert.

Comment: I edited the telnet session output in my question. The chained certificates should be set up correctly as the TLS test at http://www.checktls.com verfies certificate chaining and does not report any errors.
@NickW: I was a little unprecise. Before I was using TLS with RC4 cipher from the standard postfix configuration and changed that to DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA cipher. Other than that I didn't do anything.

Comment: See this : `530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first` that means you want the amazon server to use STARTTLS, but it isn't.

Comment: @NickW: Thank you so much! That pointed me to the right direction. I had smtp_tls_security_level set to 'encrypt', which enforces TLS. After chaning it to 'may' it worked. Do you want to post this as an answer so I can accept it? ...I am really 'amazed', that Amazon does not support STARTTLS

Comment: Sure, I'll do that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you logging shows, you are offering STARTTLS, and as you have specified `smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt` your server will not accept unencrypted mail connections.

This is confirmed by the [postfix manual](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html):

> At the "encrypt" TLS security level, messages are sent only over TLS encrypted sessions. The SMTP transaction is aborted unless the STARTTLS ESMTP feature is supported by the remote SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

### Postfix: Debugging incoming SMTP connection

*It is a recipe how to get more informations about the problem*

Try to get more debug info about incoming SMTP connections causing problems.  Use `debug_peer_list` configuration option:

```
debug_peer_list = amazon.com
```

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#debug_peer_list

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I will post the logging result in my question